Xcode Error When Attempting to Release iOS App Build for Flutter Project - How to Resolve?

I'm working on releasing an iOS app build for my Flutter project, but I keep encountering an error in Xcode during the process. Here are the steps I've already tried:

Uninstalled and reinstalled Xcode to ensure I have a fresh setup.

Cleared the build folder in Xcode.

Ran several different commands suggested by ChatGPT, including commands for cleaning the build, updating dependencies, and resetting Xcode settings.


Despite these attempts, the issue persists. Has anyone encountered a similar problem, or does anyone have suggestions on how to resolve this error? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
